# Typescript return number after typeof == number check and use generic key as string

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function that looks like this:

```
function numberHiddenOrNull<DataEntity, EntityKey extends keyof DataEntity> 
(d:DataEntity, key:EntityKey): number | null {

    if (typeof d[key] === "number") return d[key];

    const hidden = `Hidden_${key}`
    if (typeof d[hidden] === "number") return d[hidden];
    return null;

}
```

Basically, it only gives me the number if either that key is a number, or if a 'hidden' version of that key `Hidden_` is a number, otherwise null. This is a common case across multiple different types in the project.

Typescript is throwing me the compiler error:

```
Type 'DataEntity[EntityKey]' is not assignable to type 'number | null'.
```

Is there any way to have the compiler understand that I only want to return there if I know the value is indeed a number?

Also - is it possible to guard against a generic `keyof` into a string? Seems like it should be safe. I am getting:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
```

Comment: Don't you mean to do ``const hidden = `Hidden_${key}`; if (typeof d[hidden] === "number") return d[hidden];``?

Comment: oh, yeah thanks will update now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll be happiest implementing it like this:

```
function numberHiddenOrNull<T, K extends keyof T>(
    d: T, key: K
): number | null {

    const dKey = d[key];
    if (typeof dKey === "number") return dKey;

    const dHidden = d[`Hidden_${key}` as keyof T];

    if (typeof dHidden === "number") return dHidden;
    return null;

}
```

One problem you were running into before is that property checks with bracket notation don't trigger control-flow analysis narrowing unless the property in brackets is a string [literal](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).  So checking `typeof d[k] === "number"` does not change the observed type of `d[k]` since `k` is a variable and not a string literal like `"foo"`. In the checks you perform, `d[key]` doesn't narrow because `key`'s type is a generic type parameter, an `d[hidden]` doesn't narrow beause `hidden`'s type is just `string`.

The workaround for this is as I showed above: copy the property into a new variable.  The new variable (`dKey` and `dHidden`) is no longer any kind of property access, so checking its type with `typeof` will indeed narrow its type.

---

The other problem is that the value stored in `hidden` is not known to be a key of the `d` object, so the compiler rightly complains that this access is unsafe.  I mean, if I had an object `{a: 1, b: 2}` and I tried to index into it with key of type `string`, the compiler should warn me about this.  Only the string literals `"a"` and `"b"` or the union of them `"a" | "b"` would be safe keys in this case.  In the generic case, `key` is known to be `keyof T`, but `` `Hidden_${key}` `` is not.

If you want to do something that you think is safe but the compiler does not, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler not to worry.  So in the above example, I assert that  `` `Hidden_${key}` `` is of type `keyof T`, which then allows the access.  The compiler assumes that `dHidden` is of type `T[keyof T]`, which is good enough for the rest to compile.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGEBbARgUwE4AkYAmBmYA8tgHIgA21APACoA0iA0opgB5QkEDOiANaYAnnGCIGAPgAUAKESLEBAFySWwkWtZyAlGpQYciAD7Ia1RAG85CpRAR8oy1qMQBeZQG1NAXQDcdoowEjJQIgAOmOIubu7xiABEhljYibqI2JhQINhIBK4igUGIDmBOyvhEJB7eAAZVxGAA+gAkVpoAvnWIAIYCmjEMAbZKiCGIYZHREgSNNfGeyWip6ZnZufnzYIFjWTl55rTFnUA)

Comment: Wow very cool to know that about the control-flow analysis. Yeah the key typing makes sense; I figured that since I am checking the type of the value anyway, it can't be dangerous if there is no key, it will just return null. Perhaps I am still stuck in traditional JavaScript thinking here... Thank you for the help!